# Why does $n^c$ grow faster than $2^n$?

Tags: limits

For every finite case, I can find a $c$ where $2^n = n^c$, so why is this true?

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^n}{n^c} = 0$$

From the finite cases it seems like $2^n$ grows faster because we can find a $c$ to match it at any $n$.

Comment: I'm sorry, it is false.

Comment: It is false?.. It's in a textbook with example problems with solutions. Suppose they made a mistake then?

Comment: Do not confuse $\lim\limits_{c\to\infty}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n}{n^c}$ with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\lim\limits_{c\to\infty}\frac{2^n}{n^c}$ with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n}{n^c}$.  These are all different problems.  You specifically asked about the last one, and in this last one $c$ is a single value, whatever it happened to be, that once we started the problem never changes from then on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $c$ then will depend on $n$. The whole idea of what makes a polynomial into a polynomial is that its power is not dependent on the argument, i.e. in $x^5$, $5$ is independent of $x$.

If I keep varying the exponent with $x$, you end up with something like $x^{f(x)}$, which is a general form that can grow faster than exponentials. But that does not make it into a 
polynomial.